# Parse Exception in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I am using ***[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)*** and I am getting `ParseException` as shown below.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Jul 02 21:56:10 AST 2012"
```

Code I have have is

```
    String dateStr = "Mon Jul 02 21:56:10 AST 2012";
    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy ");

    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in parsing date ********");
    }

    String formattedDate = "";
    if (date != null) {
        formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
    }
    System.out.println("Formatted date is " + formattedDate);
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

### Update 1

I also tried with

```
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy ");
                                                                  ^
```

but still same exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works (with `z`, and not `Z`), as soon as I specify that the date format should use the symbols of the English locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
readFormat.setDateFormatSymbols(DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

As per eran, you also have extra space after yyyy: `yyyy ")`. Remove that extra space.

Comment: +1. Also, in the question there's an extra space after the 'yyyy'. Should be removed for this solution to work.

Comment: @eran : The problem was space.. Everything works perfect without JB second line `.setDateFormatSymbols()`

Comment: @FahimParkar: it works only because your default locale is already English.

Answer (score 0):

The format code `Z` is for timezone offset, like `-0800`, while the format code `z` is for the written format, such as `PST` or `CST`, according to what's described at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Double-check that your parse pattern has the intended capitalization.